# Pgadmin4: Export/decrypt saved Passwords

Tags: migration, pgadmin-4

Since we are migrating pgadmin from sqlite to a postgres Database, one of my main problems right now is to export the stored servers with their saved passwords.
The passwords are encrypted using the Master Password. Is there any option to decrypt them manually using the master PW? And maybe further already a solution for a pgadmin sqlite to postgres migration?